# Get a list from column 2 if column 1 contains a portion of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns, (Reports and Data Names).

```
Reports                 Data Names
Report 1, Report 3      Total Number
Report 2, Report 3      Total Complete
Report 1, Report 2      Total Fails
```

I need a list of data names that are from "Report 1" without blank rows. I want to see for report 1:

```
Total Number
Total Fails
```

I want to see for report 3:

```
Total Number
Total Complete
```

I cant get the formula i have attached to search just want "report 1" and anything else, it only works if i use the entire string "Report1, Report3"

```
=INDEX('Data Points'!B:C,SMALL(IF('Data Points'!B:B="Report 1",ROW('Data Points'!B:B)-ROW(INDEX('Data Points'!B:B,1,1))+1),ROW()),2)

=Index(Range,Small(If(Range="Report1",Row(Range)-Row(Index(Range,1,1))+1),Row(),2)
```

The last Row() formula is used to start the Small Kth at 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, entered as an array formula:

```
=INDEX('Data Points'!C:C,SMALL((IFERROR(SEARCH("Report 1",'Data Points'!$B$2:$B$4),0)>0)*ROW('Data Points'!$B$2:$B$4),COUNTIF('Data Points'!$B$2:$B$4,"*Report 1*")+ROW(A1)-1))
```

Comment: This only pulls the first value, even if the search is not found

Comment: @ray Good call, that's what I get for not testing first.  Corrected, see updated answer.